# spresenseの自動リセットについて

Tags: spresense

spresenseにて長期間計測装置を作りたいと考えております（メインボード＋LTE拡張ボード）。現在、不定期にフリーズしている問題点が残っており、watchdog監視に挑戦中ですがうまくいかず苦戦しています。
watdchdog以外に、spresenseを強制リセットする方法を模索しています。

拡張ボードでは、リセットピン用意されていますが、LTE拡張ボード使用時に、ハードリセットをする方法があればご教授いただきたいです。また、マイコンの死活監視について、参考サイトや方法などございましたらご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: watchdog監視でどのように苦戦しているのでしょうか？WDTは通常一定期間の間にポート等にアクセスがなかったらリセットかけるようにします。従ってソフトでは定期的にポートにアクセスし、フリーズした場合は、それが止まるので、CPUリセットが発生します。

Answer (score 1):

すでに試されているかもしれませんが、Spresennse Arduino Library であれば [Watchdog ライブラリ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_watchdog_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA)を使うことができます。サンプルのコードそのままですが、次のように簡単に使えるので便利ですよ。

```cpp
#include <Watchdog.h>

#define BAUDRATE                (115200)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  Serial.println("reset!!");
  Watchdog.begin();
}

void loop() {
  static int delay_ms = 1000;
  Watchdog.start(2000);

  Serial.println("Sleep " + String(delay_ms) + "ms");
  usleep(1000 * delay_ms);

  /* Check remain time for watchdog bite */
  Serial.println(String(Watchdog.timeleft()) + "ms left for watchdog bite");

  /* Kick a watchdog */
  Serial.println("Kick!");
  Watchdog.kick();

  /* Increase wait time */
  delay_ms += 100;

  /* Stop a watchdog */
  Watchdog.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ARM系のCPUであればシステムリセットの命令があったりしますが、それをどうするつもりでしょうか。
フリーズしているのを検出するのは、外部回路（例えばWDT）がないと不可能です